# Accessing string from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I have datagridview in form1 and through form1 I open form2 and through form2 I open form3 and `string named vyber_ID_K` placed in Form1 needs to be accessed in Form3 (I need to get its value in Form3)

this is placed on button click in form1

```
 form2 a = new form2 ("Novy");
        string vyber_IDK = (string)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID_K"].Value.ToString();
        a.vyber_ID_K = vyber_IDK;
        a.Show();
        a.Closed += klient_Closed;
```

I would like to access `vyber_ID_K in form 3`, how it can be done? I tried to set `public string vyber_ID_K in form2 and pass it similary to form3 but I get null`. Am I doing it right? Is there any other better solution please?

Thanks in advance.

My step-by-step according to Servy:

1. button click in Form 1

   Func vyberIDKGetter = () => dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID_K"].Value.ToString();

   ```
       try
       {
       form2 = new form2 ("Novy");

       a.vyberIDKGetter = () => dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID_K"].Value.ToString();
       a.Show();
   ```

   }
2. button click in form2

   public Func vyberIDKGetter;
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
       nova_platba b = new nova_platba("novy");
       b.vyberIDKGetter();
       b.Show();
       b.Closed += klient_Closed;
     }
3. In form3

   ```
   Func<string> vyberIDKGetter = veberIDK;


      string vyberIDK = vyberIDKGetter();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"
               INSERT INTO kliplat (datum,text,castka,akce,subkey,priznak,rocnik) 
               VALUES (@datum,@text,@castka,@akce,@subkey,@priznak,@rocnik);
               SELECT scope_identity();
               ", spojeni);


        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subkey", vyberIDK);
   ```

Comment: It sounds more like you need to rethink your layout, but bendeg's answer is one way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue here is that the value that you want doesn't exist yet when you're constructing `Form2`, or even `Form3` for that matter.  It needs to have some means of accessing the data *at some point in the future*.  We can get this behavior by leveraging delegates.

Rather than passing a `string` to `Form2`, when that form is constructed (since we don't know what the string will be yet) pass a `Func<string>`.  That object will be a method that, when invoked, will provide a string that represents the needed value.  `Form1` can define it like this:

```
Func<string> vyberIDKGetter = 
    () => dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID_K"].Value.ToString();
```

Then in `Form3` when it's holding onto the function that was passed it can get the string out by simply invoking that delegate:

```
Func<string> vyberIDKGetter = [...];
string vyberIDK = vyberIDKGetter();
```

This approach to solving the problem is particularly adventageous in that `Form3` doesn't need to know anything about `Form1` or `Form2`.  If there is some other caller that wants to use it they can provide their own delegate instead.  If there is a developer handling the coding of each form they don't need to communicate all of the internal details of each form to each other, they can just handle the passing of this delegate and then be able to treat the caller/callee as a black box.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your answer. I'm quiet begginer may I ask what does mean "when that form is constructed" ? I should place into form2_Load event or when opening Form2 on button click ? So the step-by-step is like 1) pass when opening form2 a = new form2 a.Func<string> 2. (I'm not sure where to define Func<string> ) 3. I should invoke in Form3 Func<string< vyberIDKGetter = .... ? May you please help me with it?

Comment: @Marek You should define it in `Form1`, as I've shown.  You should then pass it into `Form2` through either it's constructor, or assigning it to a property just after construction.  You should then have the second form pass it to the third in just the same manor.  At that point `Form3` has the `Func<string>` object as a field/property, can can invoke it as I showed by directly accessing that field/property; there's no real need to use a local variable.

Comment: Servy thank you so much for your kindness, may you please check my edit?

Comment: @Marek `Func<string>` is the *type* of the object, much like `string` is the type of a string object.  You need to either create a property with some name that has that as its type, that you set, or create a parameter to the forms' constructor of that type, in which you pass the value in.  `a.Func<string>` isn't meaningful; you need to specify some property that you created, not a type.  (And to do that, you have to first create a property.)

Comment: Sorry for my non-stop disturbing but can you please check my 1st step if it is passed correctly? I'm still passing null. Not sure why. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @Marek In you're first step you're *invoking* the delegate; you should be *setting* the delegate: `a.vyberIDKGetter = vyberIDKGetter;`.  You don't actually need a local variable there (although having it is fine).  You can just write: `a.vyberIDKGetter = () => dataGridView1.[...]`

Comment: Thanks, Now I have successfully passed it from form1 (what a surprise for me) But when I set breakpoint in my step 2 on b.vyberIDKGetter(); the value is null. Will you please help me again? I'm so sorry for disturbing.

Comment: @Marek Once again in step two you're *invoking* the delegate, you're not *assigning a value to it.  You should be taking the delegate that as passed from form one and assigning it to the property on form 3, once again, so that it can be invoked at a later point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a public getter/setter around the string:

```
public string Vyber_ID_K 
get
{
    return vyber_ID_K;
}
set
{
    vyber_ID_K  = value
}
```

That you need a reference from Form 1 in Form 2, and from Form 2 in Form 3. So you can access
each Form.

You can't use a string as Referenced Parameter, becuase it is an immutable class. [String C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

That is a really odd that you pass a parameter via the constructor

```
form2 a = new form2 ("Novy");
```

and in the same time you pass another parameter via the property

```
a.vyber_ID_K = vyber_IDK;
```

Why don't you instead pass all parameters via the constructor?

```
string vyber_IDK = (string)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID_K"].Value.ToString();
form2 a = new form2 ("Novy", vyber_IDK);
```

and in Form2

```
public class form2 
{
  private string Name { get; set; }
  private int vyber_IDK { get; set; }

  public form2( string Name, int vyber )
  {
     this.Name = Name;
     this.vyber_IDK = vyber_IDK;
  }
```

Then, passing anything to `form3` from `form2` works in the same way

```
form3 f = new form3( this.vyber_IDK );
```

Comment: What he's doing there isn't working.  The grid view isn't being filled in at the time form2 is constructed.  He wants `Form3` to be able to get the value of the data grid at some point in the future after it has already been created.  His current code is just passing along a null string because the data grid hasn't been populated yet.

Comment: @Servy: What you write makes sense but I've reread his post and haven't found any clue on that future access. Rather, he creates the form (first line) while the data is already available (second line). I think this needs to be clarified by the OP.